# Does the await keyword in Dart automatically handle data dependency?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, dart

for example in the following code

```
var Cake thisCake = new CheeseCake();
thisCake = await fetchGreenTeaCakeOnline();
if (thisCake.isCheeseCake) {
    print('This is still a cheese cake.')
} else {
    print('The cake is updated')
}
```

`thisCake` is originally an instance of `cheeseCake`, and it will be asynchronously assigned as an instance of `GreenTeaCake`. Will the `if` clause wait for the fulfillment of `await` assignment to execute, or it will execute disregard of the data dependency of `thisCake`?

update: fixed syntactical typo thanks to [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` waits for the completion of a `Future`.
In your example `thisCake` will get the `Future` assigned and then `await` waits for it to complete.

You probably rather want

thisCake = await fetchGreenTeaCakeOnline()

This way `await` waits for the `Future` to complete and the futures value is assigned to `thisCake`

Comment: Thank you Günter, this is a typo.  I indeed mean `thisCake = await fetchGreenTeaCakeOnline()`, and I read more into the doc and think that it handles the data dependency.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "data dependency". You can use `fetchGreenTeaCakeOnline().then((thisCake) { if (thisCake.isCheeseCake) {` to see what `await` is doing under the hood. When The `Future` completes, the callback passed to `then(...)` is executed and the value is passed. `await` just makes nicer syntax.

Comment: okay, thanks, I think you have answered the question. By data dependency I mean will the `if` clause be executed before the future completes.

Comment: Ok, that's basically all `await` is for, to ensure the code after `await` is done before code below is executed. You need to ensure that the whole chain of `Future`s somewhere inside `fetchGreenTeaCakeOnline()` are awaited as well otherwise async execution can still be outstanding without the top-level `await` being able to await it.